# Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, facebook-authentication

I am running to this error for a couple of days while I am trying to find some solution for it

I am applying a Facebook authentication to my Expo app . Android everything is working as expected while is ios **ONLY** getting this error

> [Error: Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook:
> {"error":{"message":"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not
> match the Viewing
> App","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AatQy0aKnSRI8b_pOTa4txS"}}]

While I am searching everybody is pointing that means the **AppID** or **AppSecret** provided to firebase is wrong but I am 100% sure it's right as it's working well with android and the user is being authenticated and added to users so my expectations there is something wrong with ios config

***Notes***

App is directing to FB successfully and return token through ios

**Again I am 100% sure of my AppID and AppSecret is correct as I copied paste them**

```
Expo CLI 3.21.9 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.18.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      npm: 6.14.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  4.0.0.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~37.0.3 => 37.0.12
      react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
      react-dom: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
      react-native-web: ~0.11.7 => 0.11.7
      react-navigation: ^4.3.9 => 4.3.9
```

[image]

I will be very grateful if someone is willing to help me with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got to know what is wrong. Everything is ok for the configuration and setting up the peoject.

The problem is the **Expo** doesn't support facebook authentication in development mode and as per docs it's supported only with standalone apps which with me not working as well

Waiting expo to update something so it could be used

Comment: this is wird bcause for me works on android but not on Ios

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue, but working correctly on Adroid and not in IOS im not assuming is a problem of development mode; my current status is this:
Android Emulator -> clicking on 'login with facebook' it opens a popup to login using my app (FB App name is correct, icon is correct and so on)
IOS real device -> clicking on 'login with facebook' it opens facebook and want to login to Expo FB App (Expo name, Expo icon and so on) so, when i login, of course firebase get the wrong App id (the one passed is the Expo App ID, not mine)
i guess there's something on IOS Expo that intercept APP_ID from Facebook init and replace it with its own APP_ID

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and spent over 2 days debugging all the code. In the end, it all came down to the "App ID" and "App Secret Key" that I was so sure I copied from the FaceBook Dev page to the Firebase FaceBook Authentication page. Somehow, while copying the Secret Key, the words "App Secret" got prefixed to it.

Secondly, the "OAuth redirect URI" that you get from the Firebase screen where you enter the App ID/Key, needs to be copied back to the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" field in Facebook Dev Site (Application > Products > Facebook Login > Settings).

Comment: could you elaborate more with images cause Auth redirect URI where you enter the App Id/Key (where is this key on firebase or ...?)

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, the problem was that if, for example, you have created an account with (email@example.com) and you log in with Facebook registered with the same email (email@example.com) account, it will not work until you delete account (email@example.com) manually from Firebase.